# Question about proof of the Euler product formula for the Riemann zeta function.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, riemann-zeta

> For $z\in\mathbb{C}$, with $\Re(z)>1:$$$ \zeta(z)=\prod_p \frac1{1-p^{-z}}.$$

**Proof:**

Let $z\in \mathbb{C}$, with $\Re(z)>1$. Write the prime numbers down as $2=p_1<p_2<p_3<\dots$. Then the given product can be expressed more explicitly as $$ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{1-p_n^{-z}}.$$

We then have

$$ \prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac1{p_k^z}+\frac1{p_k^{2z}}+\frac1{p_k^{3z}}+\dots\right) = \sum_{m_1,\dots,m_n=0}^{\infty}\frac1{(p_1^{m_1}\cdots p_n^{m_n})^z}.$$ The unique prime factorization of natural numbers implies that $$\left| \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{k^z}-\sum_{m_1,\dots,m_n=0}^{\infty}\frac1{(p_1^{m_1}\cdots p_n^{m_n})^z}\right|\le \sum_{k=p_n}^{\infty}\frac1{|k^z|}\to 0, \text{as } n\to \infty. $$ This proves that $\zeta(z)$ approaches $\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac1{p_k^z}+\frac1{p_k^{2z}}+\frac1{p_k^{3z}}+\dots\right)$ for $n\to\infty$. The factors of this product are geometric series, so the result follows.

**Questions:**

- Why do we explicity mention that we order the prime numbers the way we do. Does the convergence depend on this order?
- "The unique prime factorization of natural numbers implies that $$\left| \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{k^z}-\sum_{m_1,\dots,m_n=0}^{\infty}\frac1{(p_1^{m_1}\cdots p_n^{m_n})^z}\right|\le \sum_{k=p_n}^{\infty}\frac1{|k^z|}\to 0, \text{as } n\to \infty." $$ I don't see where the upper bound comes from, and how does it approach $0$ as $n\to\infty$ (since that would just imply that $p_n$ would be a very large prime number)?

Thanks.

Comment: Let $Lpf(n)= \max_{p | n} p$ be the largest prime factor then $|\zeta(s)-\prod_{p\le k} \frac1{1-p^{-s}}| = |\sum_{n,Lp(n) > k}n^{-s}| \le \frac{k^{1-\Re(s)}}{\Re(s)-1}$